# Convert Java code documentation to C#

Tags: c#, .net, xml, comments

I have to change a couple of jave method comments to C# comment syntax and I was searching for a tool which is able to do this conversion.

Does anybody know a tool which is able to convert comments from java to c# style?

Answer (score 1):

with Visual Studio is a tool named JbImp.exe delivered that converts Java to J# (what is MSIL and can converted to C#). But I haven't tried it by my self and can not definitely say if it also converts comments to XML.